# Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: 'undefined'

Tags: redux

I keep getting this error

```
"throw new Error(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? formatProdErrorMessage(2) : "Expected the root reducer to be a function. Instead, received: '" + kindOf(reducer) + "'");"
```

```
const redux = require('redux');
const createStore = redux.createStore()
const combineReducers = redux.combineReducers()

// Action Creators

function orderCake() {
    return {
        type: 'CAKE_ORDERED',
        payload:1
    }
}


// States
const initialStateCake = {
    numberOfCakes : 10
}





const cakeReducer = (state = initialStateCake, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
        case 'CAKE_ORDERED':
        return {
            ...state,
            numberOfCakes: state.numberOfCakes - action.payload
        }
        default: 
        return state
  }
}




const store = createStore(cakeReducer) 
store.dispatch(orderCake())



console.log("Initial State", store.getState())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. Thank you for adding the code and the error message, but please do [edit] your question to explain what this code is supposed to do, what you'd like us to help you with and what you've already done yourself to debug this.

Comment: I assume this is spread over multiple files in reality? Please share your imports and export.

Comment: Also, please be aware that this is a very outdated style of Redux (pre-2019) and you should probably not be learning from the tutorial you are following right now, as Redux changed significantly since. Please follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts)

Answer (score 2):

I found solution here, just remove the parenthesis from createStore

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxWy9Nz63to&ab_channel=UnitedTopTech

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the same tutorial and got an error like this. The second line of code is wrong because `redux.createStore` is not a function, it is a property of the redux object. To create a store with redux, the correct code would be:

```
const redux = require("redux");
const createStore = redux.createStore;
const store = createStore(reducer);
```

If you are interested you can see the work which I have done when doing this tutorial [here](https://github.com/NirmalSankalana/redux-toolkit-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

easy mistake, below line

```
const createStore = redux.createStore()
```

should be

```
const createStore = redux.createStore
```

or

```
const createStore = redux.legacy_createStore
```